# Node/electron: child_process.exec reporting error even though it is successful

Tags: node.js, electron

I am executing:

```
child_process.exec('pkill -9 -f someprog', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

What I see on my side 100% is that `someprog` gets killed immediately (good) but I get the following `err`:

```
{
    "stack": "Error: Command failed: pkill -9 -f someprog

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:312:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:672:12)",
    "message": "Command failed: pkill -9 -f someprog",
    "killed": false,
    "code": null,
    "signal": "SIGKILL",
    "cmd": "pkill -9 -f someprog"
}
```

If I try this from the command line, I can verify that the exit code is 0, so why is child_process.exec reporting an error?

Note, this is with Electron 10.1.5 (i.e. node 12.16.3), running under Ubuntu 18.

Comment: It's possible that `child_process` is sensitive to data printed on `stderr`. I'm not sure if this really is the case but in another programming language, `tcl` the `exec` function behaves this way. Any data on `stderr` is considered an error condition even though a lot of programmers have gotten used to printing to `stderr` for progress updates etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The node `child_process.exec` docs suggest that an error argument will only be there for a non-zero exit code, but it's possible I'm reading it wrong... In any case, there's also no output on `stderr`...